# Download files temporarily from a git repo - leaves orphaned git process

Tags: python-3.x, git, temp, contextmanager, gitpython

I want to get the contents of a git repo into a temporary directory so I can copy the files I need elsewhere and then delete the rest. I've done this:

```py
import git
import contextlib
import tempfile

@contextlib.contextmanager
def temp_repo(url: AnyPath) -> Generator[git.Repo, None, None]:
    """
    Returns a git repo cloned to a temp directory
    """
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdirname:
        yield git.Repo.clone_from(url, tmpdirname)
```

... which allows me to have `with temp_repo(my_url)` to manage the lifetime of the repo. Now I'm wondering if simply deleting the entire local clone is sufficient cleanup - I think it isn't since I'm getting some git.exe processes leaked (multiple appearing in task manager). Is this stupid/ what is a good way of temporarily accessing files from a remote?

Comment: Possibly related, though it doesn't seem it should leak processes since git calls should exit https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#leakage-of-system-resources

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with git on windows, but cloning a repository and then deleting files should be sufficient. I do not know why there would be git processes in the background, and it's not something I've observed myself.

If you're using github, it might be preferrable to use the raw content URL github specifically provides for this purpose:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<project>/<branch>/<filepath>
```

You can get it for any file in any repository just by opening up the file and github, and then clicking "raw". This file can be downloaded via curl, wget, or another appropriate tool.